# Refreshing page problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am just started to learn MVC, and I am using MVC3 with Razor View engine.

I have a view that has 6 cascading dropdownlists, say `Countries`, `Priorities`, `Titles`, `PIssues`, `MIssues`, `Documents`.

- When `selectIndex` changed for `Countries`, it should populate all other five dropdownlists.
- When `selectIndex` changed for `Priorities`, it also populate all other five dropdownlists.
- When `selectIndex` changed for `Titles`, it should populate `PIssues`, `MIssues`, and `Documents`.
- When `selectIndex` changed for `PIssues`, it should populate `MIssues`, and `Documents`.
- When `selectIndex` changed for `MIssues`, it should populate `Documents`.

I have tried many different approaches, but I alwasys end up with duplicated dropdownlists.

For instance, when I change selection for `Countries`, six new dropdownlists were created besides the original six.

What's the best approach for a solution to problem like this?

Sorry about the long description and no code. If I include the code, it'd be the whole project. I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

if you are coming from classic ASP.Net (webforms) like I was, you should know that MVC does not behave like webforms. MVC doesn't do servers side onClick events (please correct me if I'm wrong). You will probably have to load the values from ajax and a JSON results from your MVC controller.